# Converting httpresponse to main data or to html free data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, httpresponse, urlfetch

I am on Google Apps script. Getting data using -

`var httpresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);`
`var httpData = httpresponse.getContentText();`

Need to filter out data, rather than processing all HTML content in httpData, how to convert to data as we see on browser. Simply the main content. As if, when we open page on browser, select all, copy, and paste on notepad... that is what i mean by main content

is it feasible..?

Comment: What response do you get and what result do you want?

Comment: httpData has the full HTML code as one can see by going in inspect. 
What I want is all the text present on webpage - and not its html/css/etc.. code. @DmitryKostyuk

Comment: Can you please paste both of those into your question?

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk Thanks, got the soln. using using XmlService - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after researching, i got What I wanted. adding a below line of code removes all the HTML tags.

`var realData = httpData.replace( /(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');`

`console.log(realdata)`

Although not perfect, it does remove 95% of the html.

Another 100% working soln - using XmlService - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service

`var doc = XmlService.parse(d5); var root = doc.getRootElement();`

Answer (score 0):

The browser has rendered the page.

In Google Apps Script, you may need to replace the tags yourself.

An alternative would be to scrape with a Scriptable Headless Browser's API to get the plain text.